# Matching double curly braces in Emacs regular expression?

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

I am creating a simple mode for emacs that finds certain markup tags.  One of the things needed is to mark footnotes between double curly braces. {{like this}}  I am having trouble having this to working with the regex `"\\(\\{[^}]*\\}"`.  I feel like I am very close, but the regex causes many issues.  What am I missing for this pattern to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern matches one or more chars wrapped in double curly braces:

```
\{\{[^}]+\}\}
```

In your pattern the first opening brace was a regular one `(` ...

Comment: Does emacs have look-ahead? If so, the inner expression should not be `[^}]+`, but `((?!\}\}).)+`.

Comment: Does this answer really work for Emacs?  `{` and `}` should not be escaped if you want literal matches in Emacs' old-school regexp.

@Tomalak What's the benefit of using zero-width assertion here?

Comment: @event_jr The advantage would be that you can match over a single `}` and only *actual* double braces end the match. `[^}]` cannot do this.

Comment: @Tomalak Unfortunately, Emacs' regexp syntax does not support this construction, so you would have to redact to a more explicit approach for the inner expression: `\([^}]\|\}[^}]\)+`. Of course, you can have even more fun if you also want to allow multiple closing braces as long as they are escaped. http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247

Comment: @Thomas And I always thought Emacs was the most advanced text editor in the world... ;)

Comment: @Tomalak No.  There is some recent discussion on the Emacs development mailing list about adding it though.

Comment: @Tomalak No doubt about that ;-) but it's also been around for quite a while. In fact, Emacs' regexp predate POSIX regexp if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Thomas May be true but it's not a very good excuse. ;) Zero-width assertions aren't exactly the "fancy new stuff".

Answer (score 6):

What are you guys talking about?  `\{..\}` is the repetition operator in Emacs regexps, so if you want to match { and } you *don't* want to escape them.

E.g. I'd use something like `"{{\\([^}]\\|}[^}]\\)*}}"`.